# Which movie series are referenced in XKCD comic 1568?

Tags: reference, parody

When I was reading XKCD comics I came across [this one](http://xkcd.com/1568/)

[image: movie synonyms 2]

In a [previous comic](https://xkcd.com/1563/) I get it was *Star Wars*, *Lord of the Rings*, and *Star Trek*, but in this other one I only know *Wandboy* = *Harry Potter*. I suspect *Puncher* = *Rocky*.

What are the movies the above comic is parodying the names of? I don't really need to know each and every movie since just knowing the series will be enough of a clue for me to work out the rest.

Comment: Professor Whip's subtitles sound like Indiana Jones perhaps?

Comment: I edited the tags so this question could/should be reopened. It is not a "ID" question in the traditional sense.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

All XKCD comics have [individual threads](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=112500&start=40&hilit=1568) in the XKCD forums which discuss the various comics.

There is also an [Explain XKCD](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1568) wiki which can help. (Thanks to @alex_d).

From perusing the thread:

- Wandboy = Harry Potter
- Puncher = Rocky
- Tropical Boaters = Pirates of the Caribbean
- Professor Whip = Indiana Jones

Additionally, every XKCD comic has title text for it, which you can see if you hold your mouse over the image.

See if you can figure what what's being referenced in the text for this one:

> There's also the TV show based on the hit *Hot and Cold Music* books: *Fun With Chairs*, *Royal Rumble*, *Knife Blizzard*, *Breakfast for Birds*, and *Samba Serpents*.

Note: if you're going to answer the quoted text in a comment, be sure to use spoiler formatting.

In case you're wondering, the answer is:

> The *A Song of Ice and Fire* book series: *A Game of Thrones*, *A Clash of Kings*, *A Storm of Swords*, *A Feast for Crows* and *A Dance with Dragons*

Comment: *explainXKCD* is my preferred way to read the comics! Especially on a tablet which doesn’t “hover”.

Answer (score 9):

I think you have Wandboy and Puncher correct. I think user1306322 is right about Indiana Jones. He is a professor and uses a whip and the subtitles line up. I think the Tropical Boaters movies are Pirates of the Caribbean!

Comment: No, I think Wand Boy is [Willie's Magic Wand](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212612/) ;-)